# Setting environment variable in CircleCI command

Tags: linux, bash, circleci

I want to set an environment variable based on the output of a CLI command, I tried the below but it does not work

```
- run:
    name: Build web files
    command: API_URL="$(node utils/get-api-url.js)" && npm --prefix skynet/web run build
```

Why is that?

I tried the below following https://discuss.circleci.com/t/setting-environment-variables-with-a-command-fails/11034/4

```
- run:
    name: Build web files
    command: |
      API_URL: $(node utils/get-api-url.js)
      eval $(npm --prefix skynet/web run build)
```

But got

> /bin/bash: API_URL:: command not found
>   Exited with code 127

Comment: Have you tried the first version, but without the ampersand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your initial example, try this:

```
- run:
  name: Build web files
  command: |
    API_URL=$(node utils/get-api-url.js)
    npm --prefix skynet/web run build
```

Keep in mind, the variable `API_URL` wouldn't be available outside of this CircleCI step.